Ubuntu 24.04.1 LTS Error Message after onedrive update
I have Ubuntu 24.04.1 LTS and use the abraunegg onedrive service. Yesterday, Nov 17, I started my computer and there was a message that a onedrive update was available, so I ran the software updater. It had the onedrive update and a number of other items that I installed. When I start up today, I get a notification. I found the following in the /var/log/syslog file:
WARNING: Your cURL/libcurl version (8.5.0) has known HTTP/2 bugs that impact the use of this client.
Please report this to your distribution, requesting an update to a newer cURL version, or consider upgrading it yourself for optimal stability.
Downgrading all client operations to use HTTP/1.1 to ensure maximum operational stability.
Please read https://github.com/abraunegg/onedrive/blob/master/docs/usage.md#compatibility-with-curl for more information.
I am not too computer savvy. Do I have a problem that I need to fix, or was the corrective action automatically taken? Will there be a corrective update released soon?

Disclosure: I am the developer of the OneDrive Client for Linux - https://github.com/abraunegg/onedrive
The warning message you’re encountering is related to the version of curl provided by your Ubuntu distribution. Unfortunately, this version contains significant HTTP/2 bugs that remain unresolved. To address these issues, the only effective solution is to upgrade to a newer version of curl (8.10.1 or greater).
The onedrive application has implemented a workaround by automatically downgrading all HTTP operations to HTTP/1.1. While this ensures basic functionality, it does not resolve the underlying issues in the curl version provided by Ubuntu.
To resolve this, you have the following options:

Request an updated version of curl from Ubuntu
Advocate for a newer version of curl to be made available for your Ubuntu release.

Manually upgrade curl yourself
This involves downloading, building, and installing the latest version of curl from its official sources.

Use a distribution with more up-to-date packages
For example, Debian 12 offers curl 8.10.1 in its Backports repository, which you can install with minimal effort.

Implement the configuration file workaround
While this mitigates some issues, it won’t fully resolve the problems caused by the Ubuntu-provided curl version. Specifically, other issues, like unexpected application exits caused by SIGINT faults, will persist until you upgrade your curl version.

Ignore the warnings
This approach carries risks, as the issues stemming from the buggy curl version could still impact stability and reliability.


While these warnings can be ignored temporarily, upgrading curl is the only robust solution to ensure optimal functionality and avoid potential application failures.

Thank you. I do not think option 1 will get me anywhere. If I do option 2 and upgrade to 8.11, Ubuntu 24.04 does not support beyond 8.5.0-2ubuntu10.5. Will I have other problems? Will the new version replace the old or will I have two versions to confuse things?

Any new curl version should replace your existing version - but applications requiring the Ubuntu provided package then may cause issues for you. I do not use Ubuntu for a number of reasons - primary reason is the distribution decision to not keep packages up-to-date as compared to other available distributions.
Option 3 is potentially the right path forward for you - however this is your choice, and right now you have consequences (bugs in applications that are fixed elsewhere) of your existing distribution choice.
I cannot advise what path you choose to resolve this.

One last question if I may. I appreciate the help you give to people like me. You have helped me before. When I type curl --version, I get the following feedback, which suggests that curl is not installed. If it is not installed, how is OneDrive using it?

Command 'curl' not found, but can be installed with:
sudo snap install curl  # version 8.1.2, or
sudo apt  install curl  # version 8.5.0-2ubuntu10.4
See 'snap info curl' for additional versions.

The client uses 'libcurl' hence the message, and this comes from the 'curl' application. Please refer to https://github.com/abraunegg/onedrive/blob/master/docs/client-architecture.md to understand how the client uses this library to interact with Microsoft OneDrive. That the application 'curl' is not installed on your platform ... well I cant say why this is not the case .... maybe yet another Ubuntu bug|issue ....

Thanks to @abraunegg on github here is the way to install curl 8.11.0 on Ubuntu 24.04.1
https://github.com/abraunegg/onedrive/discussions/2997
This should fix the problems...

Thank you. This is exactly the step by step implementation I need for my level.

Thank you https://askubuntu.com/users/1160044/abraunegg for the detailed answer. 2 follow on questions:

I am updating the onedrive client on three machines accessing the same data on onedrive. So far I have disabled and removed the old 2.4.25 client from all machines and removed and reinstalled the repository (the old one was giving key errors on the machines updated from Ubuntu 22.04 to 24.04 so the simplest solution seemed to be to remove and reinstall the repository).
When installing the new version should I delete the old ~/.config/onedrive/ files which are left hanging?

On reinstallin the new client version on the first machine I have hit the error message in the first post. Is another option to abort before authorising with OneDrive and revert to the previous client version? What repository can I get the old 2.4.25 client from?


I still need to use the client sync in Ubuntu 24.04 because some apps can't seem to access the new nautilus integration version of the files - I was hoping that would make life much simpler but sadly not yet.

Fixed by installing curl 8.11 as per https://github.com/abraunegg/onedrive/discussions/2997
